# Cannot Find AjaxControlToolKit HTMLEditorExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a HTMLEditorExtender control onto my webpage.

In the ASPX, I have the following snippet of code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="test" runat="server"/>
```

When I attempt to build my project, I get the following compiling warning: `The type or namespace name 'HTMLEditorExtender' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit'(Are you missing an assembly reference?)`

In my code behind (C#), I tried including the following using.

```
using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor;
```

But I get the same build error.

I've been using this website as a reference: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx Is there somethign that I'm missing?

In addition, the intellisense (I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios 2012) doesn't pick up the HTMLEditor control, but it picks up other controls from the AjaxControlToolkit such as the accordian...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had the wrong register at the header of my aspx page. Included the following at the top of my ASPX page and it worked:

```
<%@ Register
Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
TagPrefix="HTMLEditor" %>
```